# WP Error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE --- when navigating CMS

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

**My issue**:  I get "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error when navigating to certain pages within the WP CMS (e.g. Plugins, Updates, Appearances).

**Troubleshooting**:
- deactivated/ reset plugins folders via FTP (has to be via FTP)
- disabled/swapped current theme
- turned on WP_DEBUG and fixed innocuous header errors

[image: This is what the error looks like]

**Other Errors**:
 - Deprecated: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect0]: The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /data/prod/resourcecentral/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1518
 - Notice: Undefined index: repositories in /data/prod/resourcecentral/wp-content/plugins/types/library/toolset/installer/includes/class-installer-dependencies.php on line 116
- Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /data/prod/resourcecentral/wp-content/plugins/types/library/toolset/installer/includes/class-installer-dependencies.php on line 116

**Conclusion**: I have no f*** idea what to do... Disabling my WP_plugins will solve my "Other Errors" issue, but the main "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" issue persists. Everything I've tried has been to no avail... Has anyone else had this issue, none of the potential fixes I find online work.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? That's where you'd find a reason for this error.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a shot in the dark but stuff like this can happen when your OS has a higher MTU Package Size size then your router/modem. I suppose this could be a misconfiguration on the web servers part.

This website explains what the MTU is and some pitfalls I guess.
http://www.networkworld.com/article/2224654/cisco-subnet/mtu-size-issues.html

You'd probably get a better response posting this in the https://serverfault.com/ with your specs and some configuration information.